# How to Add Auto Incremental ID Column to Table with data

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How to Add Auto Incremental ID Column to Table with data. ie. New column will fill with ids in old data
Old user table with data

```
Name, email,

abc, abc@gmail.com

abcd, abcd@gmial.com
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
id, Name, email,

1, abc, abc@gmail.com

2, abcd, abcd@gmial.com
```

Comment: add a proper data sample  and the expected  result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write:

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

Answer (score 0):

Alter table does no allow you to order the new field so perhaps you need to do it in 2 stages. For example

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
CREATE TABLE T (NAME VARCHAR(10),EMAIL VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO T VALUES('ABC','abc@gmail.com'),('ABCD','abcd@gmial.com');
ALTER TABLE T
    ADD COLUMN  ID INT FIRST;

UPDATE T JOIN(
SELECT NAME, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NAME DESC) RN FROM T) s
ON S.NAME = T.NAME
SET T.ID = S.RN
;

ALTER TABLE T
    MODIFY COLUMN ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;

SELECT * FROM T;
```

Where id is added and then updated for existing records using row_number with order by

With this result

```
+----+------+----------------+
| ID | NAME | EMAIL          |
+----+------+----------------+
|  1 | ABCD | abcd@gmial.com |
|  2 | ABC  | abc@gmail.com  |
+----+------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The second Alter statement then modifys id.

```
show create table t;

CREATE TABLE `t` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NAME` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EMAIL` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

If you are not on mysql version 8 or above you will need to replace the row_number bit with row number simulation using variables.
Not that it makes any difference anyway since any query would still need to include an order by to get the outcome you want.